# Class Hierarchy and Setup

Tags: java, oop

So I am trying to make a simple RPG-like text-based game to consolidate some of my studies, and I am wondering how the best way to implement this type of setup is:

Interface called Fighter > implemented by AbstractFighter > MagicFighter and StrengthFighter extend AbstractFighter. (Originally MagicFighter and StrengthFighter had their own interfaces with additional unique behaviours) but...

Now where it gets confusing is I want the player to be able to choose between these two types of Fighter, I then store this in a List(Fighter). So obviously the type I get back is always Fighter (it has to be as I dont know which implementation of Fighter the user will choose) and I can only call methods that are in the Fighter interface

One thing I could do is to write checks for what the player chose and downcast every time I need to call methods unique to the different Fighter implementations. But this would mean alot of repeated code, and sounds messy =/.

Another possibility is to run checks and add the user to a List(StengthFighter) or List(MagicFighter) based on their choice, but ultimately this just has the exact same problem as the previous 'solution'.

The final thing I can think of is to try and mirror each implementation of Fighter so that there is always a version of each behaviour for each. So for example 
void regen(); in the Fighter interface and then implemented differently for StrengthFighter and MagicFighter (Magic fighter might regen mana, strength fighter might regen rage whenever he uses an attack() (which is another issue as due to ManaFighter needing to implement regen() it is obviously public, but the use of it within StrengthFighter would be private).

Anyway, you probably get the gist by now, so il save any more textwalling.

What it boils down to; is this a flaw in my implementation. Or is this just an inevitability with OO programming? I mean, at the end of the day, how can Java know what type the result needs to be (and therefore use its methods) if it is asking the user to make a decision that determines the type.

Comment: Make Fighter have a public class that functions as a boilerplate Fighter, and extend/override MagicFighter and StrengthFighter-specific methods. The other alternative is to just make one Fighter class that handles everything based on an enum type. It's nice to OO, but when it becomes as confusing as you've presented it, cut out some of the complexities and keep it simple.

Comment: When the user choses his type, just call new MagicFighter(), and then it will call specific methods naturally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough class implementation based on interpretations of your question. Your original definition of having an interface and then an implementation and then the individual types feels complex. Instead, we want to work with individual `Fighter`s and not representations of them.

```
class Fighter {
    int hp;

    void attack() {

    }

    void move() {

    }

    void regen() {
        hp++;
    }
}

class MagicFighter extends Fighter {
    int mana;

    @Override
    void regen() {
        mana++;
        //we don't regen hp because we're magic-type.
    }
}

class StrengthFighter extends Fighter {
    int rage;

    @Override
    void attack() {
        super.attack();
        specialRegen();
    }

    void specialRegen() {
        rage++;
    }

    @Override
    void regen() {
        // does nothing
    }

    void berserk() {
        rage--;
    }
}
```

In this case, we could store a list of `Fighter`

```
List<Fighter> fighters = new List<>();
```

When we want to create a new fighter, we would determine what the user wanted and add that to the list of fighters.

```
    if (selection.equals("StrengthFighter")) {
        Fighter fighter = new StrengthFighter();
        fighters.add(fighter);
    }
```

Then, we'd call all the methods as normal. Anything shared between the two classes would not be overridden, such as `Fighter.move`. Anything that doesn't work for only one type would be overridden, like `StrengthFighter.regen`. Anything that has special additional functionality for a specific type would implement the additional functionality and make a `super` call, like `StrengthFighter.attack`.

Basically, you have the right idea already, but basically, you want `Fighter` to do as much of the shared work as possible, and then implement individual actions based on the type behind the scenes. If something needs to be checked for type, it needs to be something unique to that type of Fighter, such as `StrengthFighter.berserk`.

This reduces the need to check types except when they really matter.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for taking the time to look through my question and provide an answer. So, ultimately to call berserk() for example I need to downcast, but only when really needed?

Comment: @FinalFind yes. If a normal `Fighter` doesn't know berserk, you can't really call it. Of course, you could also write a method called `specialAbility`, but the problem with that is you don't know if the special ability applies, so in the end, hiding the fact that you want to call berserk doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the only Fighter > FighterImpl. Other staff should be implemented separately: weapons, armor, abilities, etc...

On creation you grant the fighter with abilities + weapon (restricted by abilities) + perks. Then all fighters live in the same conditions.

```
interface Fighter {
    int getSpeed(); // base fighter speed per time unit
    Armor getArmor(); 
    Weapon getWeapon(); 
    Damage attack(Fighter enemy); // animate + apply damage
    Position move();
    List<Perks> getPerks();
    List<Ability> getAbilities();
}

interface Weapon {
    DamageType getDamageType();
    int getDamage();
    void animateHit(Fighter enemy);
}

abstract class AbstractWeapon implements Weapon {
    ...
}

abstract class MeleeWeapon extends AbstractWeapon {
    ...
}

abstract class MagicWeapon extends AbstractWeapon {
    ...
}
```